# Is there a way to hover over webelement without using actions in Selenium?

Tags: testing, selenium, web

Most of the examples I have seen are using actions to hover over webelement.

Actions mouseAction = new Actions(driver);
  mouseAction.MoveToElement(someWebElement);

How do I do this without using actions? Right now if I go webelement.I get methods to click, submit etc but nothing related to mouse hover over.

Comment: Why is that you do not want to use Actions?

Comment: No.  That is what Actions was designed for.